# How can I change ID to Auto Incremental after making relationships in MySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am trying to study MySQL and JDBC so I created a database. I didn't know that I had to make my ID's auto incremental. So when I was trying to create a function for inserting data in database in JDBC, I was told that the ID's should be auto incremental and I shouldn't add them manually. As I already have added all the data and structured the database(making relationships, adding foreign and primary keys) I can't make my ID's autoIncremental, because they are foreign keys in different tables. I don't wan't to delete data from my database and start from beginning. What are my options other than giving ID's manually in JDBC?
Can I somehow change my ID's and make them Auto Incrimental?

I think that me having foreign keys in other tables is the problem. But I don't want to delete them as I have put lot's of data in my database.

This is the MySQL workbench. I tried to add. AutoIncremental from here.

[image]

The MySQL workbench applies this SQL script:

```
ALTER TABLE `university`.`student` 
CHANGE COLUMN `StudentID` `StudentID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

And Finally I get this Error:

```
ERROR 1833: Cannot change column 'StudentID': used in a foreign key constraint 'studentsection_ibfk_1' of table 'university.studentsection'
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `university`.`student` 
CHANGE COLUMN `StudentID` `StudentID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.

ERROR 1046: No database selected
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `StudentID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LastName` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `StudentGPA` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Major` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `MajorID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StudentID`),
  KEY `MajorID` (`MajorID`),
  CONSTRAINT `student_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`MajorID`) REFERENCES `major` (`MajorID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

P.S. Im working with MySQL Workbench, PHPMyAdmin and Eclipse for JDBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to make the id column a key and change the property to be autoincrement:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` INT NULL,
    `value` INT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;    

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `value`) VALUES (1, 23);
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `value`) VALUES (5, 42);
```

With the above code, I simulate a populated table with your values. Then, this is the code you're interested:

```
ALTER TABLE `test`
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST,
ADD INDEX `Índice 1` (`id`);
```

After that, you'll have an autoincrement field, so you won't need to add the id again:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`value`) VALUES (23);
```

Comment: Well, I think the problem is that there are foreign keys. Your simulation doesn't have another table. For example test2 table which has testID as a foreign key. I think Foreighn key is the reason I can't make it AutoIncrimental.

Comment: what about delete the foreign key and recreate it after make the id autoincremental?

Comment: That's the problem I don't want to do that. Because If I delete the Foreign key I'll have to delete much data. I will have to delete all the constraints and then out all the data again. Which takes lots of time. So I was looking for an easier way.

Comment: AFAIK, if you only delete the foreign key index (not the data), it won't delete your data. You may alter the table deleting the foreign key, make the autoincrement, and then alter the table adding the same the foreign key again (not tested, please, make a dump of your table or try it in a mock table)

Comment: Yeah I deleted foreign key's and it didn't delete my data. I still have some problems adding back the foreign keys, but that's probably another story. Thanks for help.